# Writing regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need the regex for following type of string:
F_E/S_(characters/digits or combination of those)_(characters/digits or combination of those)

Here / means either E or S.
How can it be written? I want to match one string in this form.How can it be done in java? I am newbie to Java.

Comment: I recommend searching google for a good regular expression tutorial. Spend one morning actually learning how to use them rather than asking someone for a specific solution to a specific problem. The problem you posed should be very easy to figure out on your own.

Comment: I strongly suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/ . It has excellent regex tutorials and reference info for any level of regex familiarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the brackets belong to the expression? Can you give an example, please.

Maybe the following *regex* works already:

```
"F_[ES]_[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+"
```

Use it in this way:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("F_[ES]_[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStringToMatch);
if (matcher.matches())
{
  // Yeah, Baby!
}
```

If there is no possibility for lower case characters, you can skip the occurrences of `a-z` in the regex pattern.

Comment: e.g. F_E_H123KF67_FKSLS343KIOP. I tried using the regex string you have given but eclipse is saying invalid escape sequence. Can you check it again?

Comment: In Java regex, do backslashes have to be escaped? I ask because they do in .NET.

Comment: Backslashes have also to be escaped in java, yes. Sorry for that, but without the brackets there is no need for escaping backslashes any more.

Comment: @Justin: A regex as written here is for the Java compiler nothing else than a String literal, so every `\` you want to arrive at the regex-compiler (the `Pattern.compile` method) has to be escaped for the Java compiler. You could read your regex from a file or user input, then there is no need for escaping. This is the same for every language which does use `\` for string escaping and does not have a special regex-syntax, independent of the framework (like .NET).

Answer (score 1):

Here it´s the regex

```
F\_[ES]{1}\_([\w\d]+)\_([\w\d]+)
```

Comment: `\w` will match `_` characters, and might also lead to odd behavior in this instance since the greedy `+` will first try to consume the `_` between the two alphanumeric groups. As an aside, `[\w\d]` is redundant.

Comment: This looks pretty noisy. I don't see why the underscore needs to be escaped. Also, some regex engines are quirky, [ES] by itself without a quantifier is taken to mean an anchor of a single character, the {1} should not be needed, but I don't know all implementations. Its readable though. +1

Answer (score 1):

the regex will be F_[ES]_[A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+

Take a look at the Java package java.util.regex and try to write a pattern matching method - its really simple. Post another question citing your java code if you get stuck somewhere..

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write it:

`F_[ES]_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+`

Comment: Clever. Maybe too clever, but +1 anyway. :)